# Synonym for “guns” and “weapons”?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

At the moment we have two questions revolving around gun control with a disjoint set of tags sitting on the front page:

---

[image]

---

It would be easy enough to retag them but I’m wondering if would make more sense to just unify the tags [guns](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guns) and [weapons](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons). What do you think?

Answer (score 9):

There are questions that are about weapons, but are not about guns, for example:

[Has weather been weaponised?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7971/has-weather-been-weaponised) , 
[Would a laser weapon visibly fire?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7946/would-a-laser-weapon-visibly-fire) , 
[Do hovercraft trigger minefields?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/13785/do-hovercraft-trigger-minefields) , 
[Does the use of tasers by the police lead to an increase in people killed by police?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14091/does-the-use-of-tasers-by-the-police-lead-to-an-increase-in-people-killed-by-pol) , 
and others which means that [weapons](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons) must remain.

However, there are many questions that are tagged as [guns](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guns) but without the [weapons](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons) tag, or quastions about guns that are tagged only as [weapons](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons). Which means that if a user  searches for a question about guns, they will not find all the relevant questions, and the same goes for weapons. In a world where all the users tag their question perfectly, questions about guns would be tagged as both [guns](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guns) and as [weapons](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons).

But since this isn't the case, and in order to avoid bad tagging, **I'm for unifying both tags under [weapons](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons)**, and add a note in the description that the tag is for all types of weapons including firearms and guns.

Answer (score 3):

All [guns](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guns) are [weapons](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons) but not all [weapons](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons) are [guns](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guns).

Normally this means they should not be merged. At the very least, though, do not make [weapons](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons) go to [guns](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guns) :-)

Comment: Okay – so retag then?

Comment: I think this makes a case for that weapons->guns is bad. But guns->weapons, given the weapons set is almost exclusively guns, seems okay to me.

Comment: Let's let the community decide, folks :-)